# “Terminal is not fully functional” warning with `less` but not with `more` (which is also `less`)

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

`less` complains about my value of `$TERM`, whereas `more` doesn’t. Which would be fine except for the fact that `more` is `less`.

Originally I was puzzled by tools suddenly disliking my `$TERM` value (I thought I configured Tmux to use `tmux` as `$TERM` a few system restarts ago), but a bigger question just entered the room: **how come two byte for byte identical binaries behave differently?**

```
❯ less
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)

❯ more
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)

❯ echo (which less) (which more)
/usr/bin/less /usr/bin/more

❯ ls -Al /usr/bin/less
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  384848 May 13 06:29 /usr/bin/less*

❯ ls -Al /usr/bin/more
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  384848 May 13 06:29 /usr/bin/more*

❯ openssl dgst -sha256 /usr/bin/less
SHA2-256(/usr/bin/less)= 8567f60723d396cb9c6e8d0a5f5206f321adbb2982d71e75cd6ec32be4256591

❯ openssl dgst -sha256 /usr/bin/more
SHA2-256(/usr/bin/more)= 8567f60723d396cb9c6e8d0a5f5206f321adbb2982d71e75cd6ec32be4256591

❯ echo $TERM
tmux

❯ tmux -V
tmux 3.3a

❯ echo $SHELL
/opt/local/bin/fish
```

This is in macOS. If it is some Mac-specific dark magic I will move this to Ask Different, of course.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The same program can behave differently if it is being run with different parameters: in your first command it receives `argv[] = {"less", NULL}` as the command-line argument array, while the second one calls it with `argv[] = {"more", NULL}`, with the 0th item in argv always being the program's own name (the "normal" args begin at 1).

This is sometimes used to create "multi-call" programs, most famously BusyBox which provides almost the entire /bin in small systems (e.g. in your Wi-Fi router).

If the 'less' program is invoked as `more`, its argument array will have `argv[0] == "more"`, which enables "[POSIX more(1) compatibility](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/less/less.1.en.html#COMPATIBILITY_WITH_MORE)" code within Less. (For example, instead of looking for additional options in the `LESS` environment variable it instead looks for them in `MORE`.)

Comment: Aha! Totally forgot the fact that a program can inspect what binary it is called as.

Comment: To be precise, it does not "inspect what binary it is called as"; it is accepting the name that the caller says it used. It can be faked or done wrong, it's up to the calling program. (And the path is not usually included.)

Comment: @alexis: Interesting point; on Linux at least it *is* actually possible for a process to `readlink("/proc/self/exe")` and get a string like `"/usr/bin/g++"` or `"/usr/bin/c++"` which interestingly does match which hardlinked name it was invoked as.  Not that this would be better, it's appropriate and expected that programs behave according to `argv[0]`, as well as more portable to implement and not relying on a mounted `/proc` filesystem on Linux.

Comment: Exactly. It is _possible_ to find this out, but that's not what normally happens and it's not what this answer describes.

Comment: It's a bit like /bin/sh being invoked with `"-sh"` in its argv[0]. There's no binary named `-sh`, the caller deliberately puts the dash there to indicate a "login shell".

Comment: “the name that the caller says it used” — yes, that’s what I meant, bad wording on my part. I’m sure it can inspect the file too, but that would be even more bonkers.

Comment: I sometimes check `argv[0]` for names like this, or look for a config file matching its filename part, to specify a custom workflow based on the binary (which is regarded as more of a generic "tool").

Comment: "The proof was valid, more or less, but rather less than more" :-) Sorry, I'll get my coat.

Comment: To be frank, I suspect that `less` itself _is_ one of the most famous examples of this, as it has had this as documented behaviour for a long time; alongside `ex`/`vi` and `sendmail`/`mailq`/`newaliases`.